Can DT column filters accept factored input to filter items in a list?
I am creating an R Shiny dashboard that includes a datatable displayed using the DT package. I have column filters displayed at the top of each column, but I want to slightly change the behavior of the filters so that a user can search for one item in a list and find all rows containing that item. For example, I have a column containing a list of food items in each row: "apples, bananas, lettuce", "pears, apples, pineapple", "apples, lettuce". I want the user to be able to select any of the individual items to filter for rows that contain that item in their list. For example, if a user selected "lettuce," the table would show the first and third examples I just listed.
This is an example of the functionality I'm looking for in an R Shiny reprex:
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Sample data frame
data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  produce = c("apples, pears", "bananas, pears, lettuce", "apples, bananas, pineapple", "apples", "pineapple, lettuce")
)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Produce Filter"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("produce_filter", "Select Produce:", 
                  choices = unique(unlist(strsplit(data$produce, ", "))),
                  selected = NULL, 
                  multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("filtered_table")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    # Get selected produce items
    selected_produce <- input$produce_filter
    
    # Check if selected_produce is NULL or empty
    if (is.null(selected_produce) || length(selected_produce) == 0) {
      # If no produce is selected, show all rows
      return(data)
    }
    
    # Filter rows where 'produce' column contains any of the selected items
    filtered <- data[sapply(data$produce, function(row) {
      any(sapply(selected_produce, function(item) grepl(item, row)))
    }), ]
    
    # Handle the case where the filtered data is empty
    if (nrow(filtered) == 0) {
      filtered <- data.frame(id = integer(0), produce = character(0))  # Return an empty data frame with the same columns
    }
    
    filtered
  })
  
  output$filtered_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(filtered_data())
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

This table does exactly what I want, but I'm wondering if it's possible for the DT table column filters to do this, rather than having an external filter that does it. I will need to apply this to several columns, so it will not be ideal to have five separate filters next to the table.

What about DT::datatable(data, filter = "top")?

It is possible but requires a lot of customization and overrides.  Here's the general idea:

The produce column in the data needs to be a factor so that when column filters are created, it creates a dropdown instead of a text box.

The options in the dropdown for the produce column need to be replaced with a unique list of produce rather than a unique list of column entries.

A custom function for filtering the data, specifically for factor columns is needed.  This is so that partial matching will work.  Normally factor columns only filter on exact matches.


library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Sample data frame
data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  produce = as.factor(c("apples, pears", "bananas, pears, lettuce", "apples, bananas, pineapple", "apples", "pineapple, lettuce"))
)

# Modified version of DT:::dataTablesFilter from version 0.19 of DT
# As of this writing, version 0.33 is the latest version of DT and has
# a different version of DT:::dataTablesFilter
dataTablesFilter <- function (data, params) {
  n = nrow(data)
  q = params
  ci = q$search[["caseInsensitive"]] == "true"
  if (length(q$columns) != ncol(data)) 
    return(list(draw = as.integer(q$draw), recordsTotal = n, 
                recordsFiltered = 0, data = list(), DT_rows_all = seq_len(n), 
                DT_rows_current = list()))
  if (length(v <- q$search[["value"]]) > 0) {
    if (!identical(q$search[["smart"]], "false")) {
      v = unlist(strsplit(gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", v), 
                          "\\s+"))
    }
  }
  if (length(v) == 0) 
    v = ""
  m = if ((nv <- length(v)) > 1) 
    array(FALSE, c(dim(data), nv))
  else logical(n)
  i = if (!identical(v, "")) {
    for (j in seq_len(ncol(data))) {
      if (q$columns[[j]][["searchable"]] != "true") 
        next
      for (k in seq_len(nv)) {
        i0 = DT:::grep2(v[k], as.character(data[, j]), fixed = q$search[["regex"]] == 
                          "false", ignore.case = ci)
        if (nv > 1) 
          m[i0, j, k] = TRUE
        else m[i0] = TRUE
      }
    }
    which(if (nv > 1) 
      apply(m, 1, function(z) all(colSums(z) > 0))
      else m)
  }
  else seq_len(n)
  if (length(i)) 
    for (j in names(q$columns)) {
      col = q$columns[[j]]
      if (col[["searchable"]] != "true") 
        next
      if ((k <- col[["search"]][["value"]]) == "") 
        next
      j = as.integer(j)
      dj = data[, j + 1]
      ij = if (is.numeric(dj) || DT:::is.Date(dj)) {
        which(DT:::filterRange(dj, k))
      }
      else if (is.factor(dj)) {
        # if the column has the "type" attribute set to "partial", use partial matching
        # otherwise, handle the default way
        if(!is.null(attributes(dj)["type"]) & attributes(dj)["type"] == "partial") {
          which(grepl(pattern = paste0(DT:::fromJSON(k), collapse = "|"), x = dj))
        } else {
          which(dj %in% DT:::fromJSON(k))
        }
      }
      else if (is.logical(dj)) {
        which(dj %in% as.logical(DT:::fromJSON(k)))
      }
      else {
        DT:::grep2(k, as.character(dj), fixed = col[["search"]][["regex"]] == 
                     "false", ignore.case = ci)
      }
      i = intersect(ij, i)
      if (length(i) == 0) 
        break
    }
  if (length(i) != n) 
    data = data[i, , drop = FALSE]
  iAll = i
  oList = list()
  for (ord in q$order) {
    k = ord[["column"]]
    d = ord[["dir"]]
    if (q$columns[[k]][["orderable"]] != "true") 
      next
    col = data[, as.integer(k) + 1]
    oList[[length(oList) + 1]] = (if (d == "asc") 
      identity
      else `-`)(if (is.numeric(col)) 
        col
        else xtfrm(col))
  }
  if (length(oList)) {
    i = do.call(order, oList)
    data = data[i, , drop = FALSE]
    iAll = iAll[i]
  }
  if (q$length != "-1") {
    len = as.integer(q$length)
    if (is.na(len)) {
      warning("The DataTables parameter 'length' is '", 
              q$length, "' (invalid).")
      len = 0
    }
    i = seq(as.integer(q$start) + 1L, length.out = len)
    i = i[i <= nrow(data)]
    fdata = data[i, , drop = FALSE]
    iCurrent = iAll[i]
  }
  else {
    fdata = data
    iCurrent = iAll
  }
  if (q$escape != "false") {
    k = seq_len(ncol(fdata))
    if (q$escape != "true") {
      k = k[as.integer(strsplit(q$escape, ",")[[1]])]
    }
    for (j in k) if (DT:::maybe_character(fdata[, j])) 
      fdata[, j] = htmltools::htmlEscape(fdata[, j])
  }
  list(draw = as.integer(q$draw), recordsTotal = n, recordsFiltered = nrow(data), 
       data = DT:::cleanDataFrame(fdata), DT_rows_all = iAll, DT_rows_current = iCurrent)
}

# this calls the custom updateFilters javascript function in the ui
# it is similar to DT::updateFilters but allows for filter_overrides which will be used here
updateFilters <- function(proxy, data, filter_overrides = list(), resetFilters = TRUE, ...) {
  filter_data <- lapply(data, FUN = function(col) {
    if(inherits(col, "factor")) return(levels(col))
    if(typeof(col) %in% c("double", "integer")) return(c(min(col), max(col)))
    if(typeof(col) == "logical") return(c(TRUE, FALSE))
    return("")
  })
  filter_overrides <- lapply(filter_overrides, FUN = function(col) {
    if(inherits(col, "factor")) return(levels(col))
    if(typeof(col) %in% c("double", "integer")) return(c(min(col), max(col)))
    if(typeof(col) == "logical") return(c(TRUE, FALSE))
    return("")
  })
  filter_data <- modifyList(filter_data, filter_overrides[intersect(names(filter_overrides), names(filter_data))])
  
  dots <- list(...)
  if(!"rownames" %in% names(dots)) dots$rownames <- TRUE
  
  if(dots$rownames) filter_data <- append(filter_data, list("ROWNAMES" = " "), after = 0)
  
  proxy$session$sendCustomMessage(type = "updateFilters", message = list(tableid = proxy$id, data = filter_data, resetFilters = resetFilters))
}


# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('updateFilters',
  function(x) {
    // outputId of the DT element
    var table = document.getElementById(x.tableid);
    // filter row of the table element within the DT element
    if(table.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0] === undefined) {
      var thead = table.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];
      var tablerow = thead.rows[thead.rows.length - 1];
    } else {
      var tablerow = table.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0].rows[0];
    }
    // loop through each cell in the filter row
    for (var i = 0, cell; cell = tablerow.cells[i]; i++) {
      // get list of all data elements for the column from the data going into the table (duplicates are okay)
      var items = x.data[Object.keys(x.data)[i]];
      items = Array.isArray(items) ? items : [items];
      // for factor columns
      if(['factor', 'logical'].includes(cell.getAttribute('data-type'))) {
        // find the selectize object
        var dropdown = $(cell).find('.selectized').eq(0)[0].selectize;
        // get the current value of the selectize object
        var curr_value = dropdown.getValue();
        // put the list of data elements in the appropriate format for the selectize
        items = items.map(function(item) {return {text: item, value: item}});
        // remove all existing options
        dropdown.clearOptions();
        // add the new options
        dropdown.addOption(items);
        // if reset filters is false, put the value of the selectize prior to updating back in
        if(!x.resetFilters) {
          dropdown.setValue(curr_value);
        }
      // for numeric or date columns
      } else if(['number', 'integer', 'date', 'time'].includes(cell.getAttribute('data-type'))) {
        // find the slider object
        var slider = $(cell).find('.noUi-target').eq(0);
        // if the column is a date column, convert the dates to numbers
        if(['date', 'time'].includes(cell.getAttribute('data-type'))) {
          items = items.map(function(item) {return Date.parse(item)});
        }
        // find the minimum and maximum of the column
        var minMaxIterate = function(arr) {
          var min = arr[0];
          var max = arr[0];
          for(var i = 1; i< arr.length; i++) {
            (min > arr[i]) && (min = arr[i]);
            (max < arr[i]) && (max = arr[i]);
          }
          return {min: min, max: max};
        };
        var min_max = minMaxIterate(items);
        var min = min_max.min;
        var max = min_max.max;
        // if the lower bound of the slider prior to updating equals the maximum prior to updating, or if reset filters is true, update the sliders and set the starting value to the new minimum and maximum
        if((Number(slider.val()[0]) == slider.noUiSlider('options').range.min &&
        Number(slider.val()[1]) == slider.noUiSlider('options').range.max) || x.resetFilters) {
            slider.noUiSlider({start: [min, max], range: {'min': min, 'max': max}}, true);
        } else {
            // if the lower bound of the slider prior to updating is between the new minimum and maximum, keep the same lower bound, otherwise set the lower bound to the new minimum
            var start = min < Number(slider.val()[0]) &&  Number(slider.val()[0]) < max ? Number(slider.val()[0]) : min;
            // if the upper bound of the slider prior to updating is between the new minimum and maximum, keep the same upper bound, otherwise set the upper bound to the new maximum
            var end = min < Number(slider.val()[1]) &&  Number(slider.val()[1]) < max ? Number(slider.val()[1]) : max;
            slider.noUiSlider({start: [start, end], range: {'min': min, 'max': max}}, true);
          }
      } else {}
    }
});"))),
  titlePanel("Produce Filter"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("filtered_table")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # use the modified dataTablesFilter function as `funcFilter`
  # set the "type" attribute for `data$produce` to "partial" so
  # that partial matching is used
  output$filtered_table <- renderDT({
    attr(data$produce, "type") <- "partial"
    datatable(data,
              filter = "top")
  },
  funcFilter = dataTablesFilter)
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("filtered_table")
  
  # after the table is rendered, update the filters with the overriden values
  onFlushed(function() {
    updateFilters(proxy, data, filter_overrides = data.frame(produce = factor(unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(data$produce), ", "))))))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

This is how it can be done using the built in DT column filters like you asked.  However, a simpler alternative may be to keep the separate filter you already have, and just move it inside the table by creating a custom container.  I can provide a separate answer for that if requested.
